# mysql: trying to accelerate query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm using mysql as DB and in order to show something in interface I have to execute such query

```
select site_id
from dim_site join
     dim_site_cat
     using(site_id)
where cat_id=8724
order by update_cat_ids_ts desc
limit 100;
```

in dim_site I have 6.5 M rows, and 1.5 of them has cat_id=8724. dim_site_cat is many-to-many table. I have index on update_cat_ids_ts but it doesn't work as you see. Now such query works too long (8.5 s) because of filesort, are there any opportunities to accelerate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to need the `dim_site` table, if I correctly understand where the columns are coming (you should always use table aliases):

```
select site_id
from dim_site_cat
where cat_id = 8724
order by update_cat_ids_ts desc
limit 100;
```

This can be sped with a composite index:  `dim_site_cat(cat_id, update_cat_ids_ts, site_id)`.

EDIT:

See, you should use table aliases.  Perhaps this will help:

```
select site_id
from dim_site s
where exists (select 1
              from dim_site_cat sc
              where sc.site_id = s.site_id and sc.cat_id = 8724
             )
order by s.update_cat_ids_ts desc
limit 100;
```

For this query, create the following two indexes:  `dim_site_cat(site_id, cat_id)` and `dim_site(update_cat_ids_ts, site_id)`.  However, you have a very large result set that needs to be ordered for the `order by`.  It may be hard to get good performance.

Comment: dim_site_cat has only 2 fields: site_id and cat_id. Links sites and cats. update_cat_ids_ts is sites characteristic

Comment: This works much better if we have 1.5 M values with such cat_id, but if we have no values with such cat_id it works too long. I try to have normal work for both variants

Comment: Do you have the index mentioned?  I don't see why it would be slower with fewer records.

Comment: Yes, I have that index, but with few records my variant works much better. Maybe the only variant is to choose query after calculation count of records with some particular cat_id?

Comment: @PavelKodentsev . . . Oh, I thought the comparison was to the longer version (that a few records takes longer than one with 1.5 million records).  This is because this form forces a scan of `dim_site`, so the performance should be rather independent of the number of rows.